# Decrease distance between two letters

Tags: letterspacing, formulas

I would like to decrease the distance between two letters in a formula, namely `$UA$`. In the formula, it is written in italics causing some space between A and U, which I would like to have gone.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `$U\mkern-3muA$`. Note `\mkern` (or `\mskip`) is meant to use in math mode with math units `mu`.

Comment: Do give `\mathit{UA}` a try.

Comment: they all work for me, thanks!